# remote closes but does not open garage door

Tags: electrical, repair, doors

I have a Linear LD003 garage door opener which is wired and I have remotes from one of two cars and some handheld remotes too. In all cases, using *any* of the remotes allows me to close one of our garage doors, but none of remotes can open the door. We have a fixed wire connection to the same door and that opens and closes it just fine, so I know it's not a mechanical problem, per se. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try turning one of the remotes upside-down :-)

Comment: So, you have two garage doors, and only one exhibits this behavior?

Comment: Correct. I have two garage doors and only one of them has gone bad.

Comment: This is an 8 year old unit that was working well until this happened

Comment: 1) Check batteries 2) Try the same remote from inside the garage 3) Try disabling any & all (flourescent) lights near the garage door motor (bc interference) 4) Keep in mind it could be the logic board / receiver on the inside 5) Good fortune

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well duh.  I'm such a idiot!  :-(

On the switching unit on the garage wall there is a small grey button that can be moved up and down.  Somehow this grey switch (marked with a padlock symbol) was moved down into the locked position -- I guess this prevents remotes from operating. The grey switch needs to be placed into the up (symbol = open padlock) for the external remotes to work.

Comment: For anyone else who has this problem in the future, note that some opener wall switches have this feature as a push-button, not a slide switch. I had exactly this same issue a few years ago, so it's too bad I didn't see your question then.